# I want duplicates to be included with my in () statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

I want to include duplicates into my query. I havent succeeded in changing my "in" statements to "joins".

My expected result is a row count of 115.

My result is a row count of 108.

If i do a "Group by" in my first subquery, i get a row count of 108.

```
select match_id item_0, item_1,  item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5, purchase_log 
    from player_matches where match_id IN
       (select x.match_id from (select matches.match_id, picks_bans.team from matches, picks_bans where picks_bans.hero_id = 1 and picks_bans.match_id = matches.match_id and is_pick = true and start_time > 1483228800 ORDER BY start_time DESC) as x 
        inner join
             (select matches.match_id, picks_bans.team from matches, picks_bans where picks_bans.hero_id 
/*this is the statement that needs to be tweaked/changed */
               IN (2,12,47,4,99) and picks_bans.match_id = matches.match_id and is_pick = true and start_time > 1483228800 ORDER BY start_time DESC) as y  on y.match_id=x.match_id and x.team!=y.team) 
    and hero_id = 1
```

You can use the opendota inbrowser data-explorer to get a better understanding of my problem.

[My subquery (returns 115)](https://www.opendota.com/explorer?sql=select%20x.match_id%20from%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20%3D%201%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20x%20%20inner%20join%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20in%20(2%2C12%2C47%2C4%2C5)%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20y%20%20on%20y.match_id%3Dx.match_id%20and%20x.team!%3Dy.team&format=table)

[My final Query (returns 108)](https://www.opendota.com/explorer?sql=select%20match_id%20item_0%2C%20item_1%2C%20%20item_2%2C%20item_3%2C%20item_4%2C%20item_5%2C%20purchase_log%20from%20player_matches%20where%20match_id%20IN%20(select%20x.match_id%20from%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20%3D%201%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20x%20%20inner%20join%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20in%20(2%2C12%2C47%2C4%2C5)%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20y%20%20on%20y.match_id%3Dx.match_id%20and%20x.team!%3Dy.team)%20and%20hero_id%20%3D%201&format=table)

**How do i get my final query to return 115 row counts?**

My query is also really slow, is this because im using "in ()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `IN` will just check if the value is present. Use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
select a.match_id, a.item_0, a.item_1,  a.item_2, a.item_3, a.item_4, a.item_5, a.purchase_log 
from player_matches a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        select x.match_id from (select matches.match_id, picks_bans.team from matches, picks_bans where picks_bans.hero_id = 1 and picks_bans.match_id = matches.match_id and is_pick = true and start_time > 1483228800 ORDER BY start_time DESC) as x  inner join (select matches.match_id, picks_bans.team from matches, picks_bans where picks_bans.hero_id in (2,12,47,4,5) and picks_bans.match_id = matches.match_id and is_pick = true and start_time > 1483228800 ORDER BY start_time DESC) as y  on y.match_id=x.match_id and x.team!=y.team
    ) b ON  a.match_id = b.match_id
WHERE hero_id = 1
```

[Here's a demo from your original link.](https://www.opendota.com/explorer?sql=select%20a.match_id%2C%20a.item_0%2C%20a.item_1%2C%20%20a.item_2%2C%20a.item_3%2C%20a.item_4%2C%20a.item_5%2C%20a.purchase_log%20%0D%0Afrom%20player_matches%20a%0D%0A%20%20%20%20INNER%20JOIN%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20x.match_id%20from%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20%3D%201%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20x%20%20inner%20join%20(select%20matches.match_id%2C%20picks_bans.team%20from%20matches%2C%20picks_bans%20where%20picks_bans.hero_id%20in%20(2%2C12%2C47%2C4%2C5)%20and%20picks_bans.match_id%20%3D%20matches.match_id%20and%20is_pick%20%3D%20true%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201483228800%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20DESC)%20as%20y%20%20on%20y.match_id%3Dx.match_id%20and%20x.team!%3Dy.team%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20b%20ON%20%20a.match_id%20%3D%20b.match_id%0D%0AWHERE%20hero_id%20%3D%201&format=table)